# Dafny verifies insertion sort using swap

Tags: swap, insertion-sort, loop-invariant, dafny

I'm working on how to use dafny to verify an insertion sort using "swap" adjacent elements but I can't find a reasonable invariant for the while loop, can anyone help me fix it? 
Here is the link: http://rise4fun.com/Dafny/wmYME

Comment: problem invariant is in line 19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems here.

First, your inner loop is not correct, because the `temp` variable is never updated. I recommend removing `temp` and using the loop condition `down >= 0 && a[down+1] < a[down]` instead.

Second, you have several issues with the inner loop invariant being ill formed (index out of range, violating precondition of `sorted`). However, instead of fixing these, I recommend throwing out both inner loop invariants and trying again.

My preferred invariant for the inner loop of insertion sort is "`a[0..up+1]` is sorted except possibly at `down + 1`". You can state this as

```
invariant forall j,k | 0 <= j < k < up+1 && k != down+1 :: a[j]<=a[k]
```

The resulting file verifies.